# How to sort pages a user admins by number of Likes

Tags: sorting, facebook-like, facebook-page

So I was looking for a way an administrator can sort facebook pages by "likes" count (for users who have a lot of pages they administrate.)

Is it possible? anyone can give me a hint on how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this [FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20page_id%2C%20name%2C%20username%2C%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%20ORDER%20BY%20fan_count%20DESC):

```
SELECT page_id, name, username, fan_count 
       FROM page 
       WHERE page_id IN 
          (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = me()) 
       ORDER BY fan_count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I've been looking for!